# Oh my lovely life

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Before I was brought to life, I chose my gender and my living environment.

I own a large piece of land for anything I like in front of my house.

I make friends with local people, by talking and sending gifts.

I improve the quality of life by donating goods to little spirits in an abandoned old house.

If I light up 4 candles, the Power That Be dictates that I'm perfect.

---

Can you find an explanation for my lovely life that best makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about

> Stardew Valley

Reasoning

> At the start of the game, players create their character, who becomes the recipient of a plot of land and a small house once owned by their grandfather. The farm plot is initially overrun with boulders, trees, stumps, and weeds, and players must work to clear them in order to restart the farm, tending to crops and livestock so as to generate revenue and further expand the farm's buildings and facilities. Players may also interact with non-player characters (NPC) that inhabit the town, including engaging in relationships with them; this can culminate in marriage, which results in the NPC helping the player's character to tend the farm.
>
>  The abandoned house to which the question refers is not "The Abandoned House" but is, in fact, the Pelican Town Community Center which initially appears as a dilapidated building and is subsequently discovered to be occupied by sprites called Junimos. During the game, you're encouraged to help the town by donating goods to rebuilding the Community Center.
>
>  The player can find a note on Grandpa's Shrine, at the far Northwest corner of The Farm, which states that Grandpa will return at the start of the third year (1st of Spring, Year 3) to evaluate the player's success. Grandpa's evaluation is directly related to the number of candles that light up around Grandpa's Shrine (there are 4 candles) at the beginning of year three. This is determined by a point system based on various milestones that were reached in the first two years.

Comment: The abandoned house part isn't accurate.

Comment: @iBug I've updated my answer accordingly.